# Check for NSDate conditions in a for loop logic

Tags: objective-c, math, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I have two `NSDates` as base conditions which I will call Date1 and Date2.

I need to count objects and have three totals. I don't actually need the objects, just the counts.

```
Group1 = objects greater than Date1. 
Group2 = objects greater than Date2.  
Group3 = objects greater than both dates.
```

I have two methods, each return one base date (Date1, Date2). 
Right now, I run a `for loop` on my `arrays` and use `if statements` to determine if the object belongs to group1, group2 or group3.

It works, but it's not pretty. I thought about implementing a `while loop`, but my `arrays` aren't ordered, so I would have to sort them, which would be about the same work.

I'm trying to find a cleaner solution,if possible, without using `if statements`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with `if` statements??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the count of `Group3` will match one of `Group2` or `Group1`, depending on whether `Date1` is less than or greater than `Date2` (the counts will match if `Date1==Date2`). This observation lets you keep two counters instead of three, and compute the third counter after the loop by comparing `Date1` to `Date2`, and picking the corresponding value for `Group3`'s count.